# Calculating differences of dates in hours between rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, difftime

I have the following dataframe (ts1):

```
                D1 Diff
1 20/11/2014 16:00 0.00
2 20/11/2014 17:00 0.01
3 20/11/2014 19:00 0.03
```

I would like to add a new column to ts1 that will be the difference in hours between successive rows D1 (dates) in hours.

The new ts1 should be:

```
                D1 Diff N
1 20/11/2014 16:00 0.00 
2 20/11/2014 17:00 0.01 1
3 20/11/2014 19:00 0.03 2
```

For calculating the difference in hours independently I use:

```
library(lubridate)
difftime(dmy_hm("29/12/2014 11:00"), dmy_hm("29/12/2014 9:00"), units="hours")
```

I know that for calculating the difference between each row I need to transform the ts1 into matrix.

I use the following command:

```
> ts1$N<-difftime(dmy_hm(as.matrix(ts1$D1)), units="hours")
```

And I get:

```
Error in as.POSIXct(time2) : argument "time2" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Use `diff`: `c(NA,diff(dmy_hm(df$D1)))`.

Comment: Thank @nicola, When I use the command I get: > diff: c(NA,diff(dmy_hm(ts1$D1)))
Error in diff:c(NA, diff(dmy_hm(ts1$D1))) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In diff:c(NA, diff(dmy_hm(ts1$D1))) :
  numerical expression has 2287 elements: only the first used

Comment: @nicola it has its perks as `diff` will set its own units default. I would do something like `res <- diff(as.POSIXct(df$D1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) ; units(res) <- "hours"`

Comment: Thanks David, The calculation looks good for res. And if I use @nicola inner part - diff(dmy_hm(df$D1)) I get same results as well. How can I add them to my source dataframe as an additional column?

Comment: I guess something like `df$N <- c(NA_real_, as.numeric(res))` should do, no?

Comment: Thanks David, works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `ts1` is as shown in Note 2 at the end.  Then create a `POSIXct` variable `tt` from `D1`, convert `tt` to numeric giving the number of seconds since the Epoch, divide that by 3600 to get the number of hours since the Epoch and take differences.  No packages are used.

```
tt <- as.POSIXct(ts1$D1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
m <- transform(ts1, N = c(NA, diff(as.numeric(tt) / 3600)))
```

giving:

```
> m

                D1 Diff  N
1 20/11/2014 16:00 0.00 NA
2 20/11/2014 17:00 0.01  1
3 20/11/2014 19:00 0.03  2
```

**Note 1:** I assume you are looking for `N` so that you can fill in the empty hours.  In that case you don't really need `N`.  Also, it would be easier to deal with time series if you use a time series representation.  First we convert `ts1` to a zoo object, then we create a zero width zoo object with the datetimes that we need and finally we merge them:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(ts1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

z0 <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "hours"))
zz <- merge(z, z0)
```

giving:

```
> zz
2014-11-20 16:00:00 2014-11-20 17:00:00 2014-11-20 18:00:00 2014-11-20 19:00:00 
               0.00                0.01                  NA                0.03
```

If you really did need a data frame back then:

```
DF <- fortify.zoo(zz)
```

**Note 2:** Input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "D1,Diff
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.00
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01
3,20/11/2014 19:00,0.03"

ts1 <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David Arenburg and @nicola:
Can use either:

```
res <- diff(as.POSIXct(ts1$D1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) ; units(res) <- "hours"
```

Or:

```
res <- diff(dmy_hm(ts1$D1))
```

and afterwards:

```
ts1$N <- c(NA_real_, as.numeric(res))
```

Comment: In both options, if you want to make sure you'll get hours differences, you will have to make sure `units` are correct, as `diff` will set the `units` to the *the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one*.