# Interpolation of constrained gaps

Tags: r, zoo, seq

In continuity to the following question:
[Efficient dynamic addition of rows in dataframe and dynamic calculation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706412/efficient-dynamic-addition-of-rows-in-dataframe-and-dynamic-calculation-in-r)

I have the following table:

```
Lines <- "D1,Diff
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.02
3,20/11/2014 19:00,0.03 <-- Gap I
4,21/11/2014 16:00,0.04
5,21/11/2014 17:00,0.06 <-- Gap II
6,21/11/2014 20:00,0.10"
```

As can be seen there are a gap of 18:00 in 20/11/2014 and two gaps of 18:00 and 19:00 at 21/11/2014.
An addition gap is between the days 20/11/2014 19:00 and 21/11/2014 16:00.
I would to interpolate (fill in) the value which the gap is up to 3 hours between the rows.
The required result should be as followed (in dataframe format):

```
Lines <- "D1,Diff
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.02
3,20/11/2014 18:00,0.025<-- Added lines
4,20/11/2014 19:00,0.03
5,21/11/2014 16:00,0.04
6,21/11/2014 17:00,0.06 
6,21/11/2014 18:00,0.073 <--
6,21/11/2014 19:00,0.086 <--
6,21/11/2014 20:00,0.10"
```

Here is the code I use that fills in the gap between days that is over 3 hours:

```
library (zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
interpolated1 <-na.approx(z, xout = seq(start(z), end(z), "hours"))
```

Comment: Your results include an interpolated value for `21/11/2014 20:00`, but that point in time was already part of the original data. Do you mean to interpolate only `21/11/2014 18:00` and `21/11/2014 19:00`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can merge `z` with a zero width zoo series `z0` which is based on a grid of hours.  This will transform `z` to an hourly series with NAs.  Then use the `maxgap` argument to `na.approx` as shown below to fill in the desired gaps only.  This still leaves NAs in the longer gaps so remove them using `na.omit` .

`fortify.zoo(z3)` would transform the result to data frame but since `z3`, the resulting series with only gaps to length 3 filled, is a time series this is probably not a good idea and it would be better to leave it as a zoo object so that you can use all the facilities of zoo.

No packages other than zoo are used.

```
z0 <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "hours"))
z3 <- na.omit(na.approx(merge(z, z0), maxgap = 3))
```

giving:

```
> z3
2014-11-20 16:00:00 2014-11-20 17:00:00 2014-11-20 18:00:00 2014-11-20 19:00:00 
         0.01000000          0.02000000          0.02500000          0.03000000 
2014-11-21 16:00:00 2014-11-21 17:00:00 2014-11-21 18:00:00 2014-11-21 19:00:00 
         0.04000000          0.06000000          0.07333333          0.08666667 
2014-11-21 20:00:00 
         0.10000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Source 1: [Creating a specific sequence of date/times in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009301/creating-a-specific-sequence-of-date-times-in-r). Answer by mnel on Sep 13 2012 and edit by Matt Dowle on Sep 13 2012

&

Source 2: [Creating regular 15-minute time-series from irregular time-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423551/creating-regular-15-minute-time-series-from-irregular-time-series). Answer by mnel on Sep 13 2012 and edit by Dirk Eddelbuettel on May 3 2012

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(data.table)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("iembry-USGS/ie2misc")
library(ie2misc)
# iembry released a version of ie2misc so you should be able to install
# the package now
# `na.interp1` is a function that combines zoo's `na.approx` and pracma's
# `interp1`
```

The rest of the code starts after the creation of your z `zoo` object

```
## Source 1 begins
startdate <- as.character((start(z)))
# set the start date/time as the 1st entry in the time series and make
# this a character vector.

start <- as.POSIXct(startdate)
# transform the character vector to a POSIXct object

enddate <- as.character((end(z)))
# set the end date/time as the last entry in the time series and make   
# this a character vector.

end <- as.POSIXct(enddate)
# transform the character vector to a POSIXct object

gridtime <- seq(from = start, by = 3600, to = end)
# create a sequence beginning with the start date/time with a 60 minute 
# interval ending at the end date/time
## Source 1 ends

## Source 2 begins
timeframe <- data.frame(rep(NA, length(gridtime)))
# create 1 NA column spaced out by the gridtime to complement the single 
# column of z

timelength <- xts(timeframe, order.by = gridtime)
# create a xts time series object using timeframe and gridtime

zDate <- merge(timelength, z)
# merge the z zoo object and the timelength xts object  
## Source 2 ends
```

The next steps involve the process of interpolating your data as requested.

```
Lines <- as.data.frame(zDate)
# to data.frame from zoo

Lines[, "D1"] <- rownames(Lines)
# create column named D1

Lines <- setDT(Lines)
# create data.table out of data.frame

setcolorder(Lines, c(3, 2, 1))
# set the column order as the 3rd column followed by the 2nd and 1st 
# columns

Lines <- Lines[, 3 := NULL]
# remove the 3rd column

setnames(Lines, 2, "diff")
# change the name of the 2nd column to diff

Lines <- setDF(Lines)
# return to data.frame

rowsinterps1 <- which(is.na(Lines$diff == TRUE))
# index of rows of Lines that have NA (to be interpolated)

xi <- as.numeric(Lines[which(is.na(Lines$diff == TRUE)), 1])
# the Date-Times for diff to be interpolated in numeric format

interps1 <- na.interp1(as.numeric(Lines$Time), Lines$diff, xi = xi,
na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 3)
# the interpolated values where only gap sizes of 3 are filled

Lines[rowsinterps1, 2] <- interps1
# replace the NAs in diff with the interpolated diff values

Lines <- na.omit(Lines) # remove rows with NAs
Lines
```

This is the Lines data.frame:

```
Lines
                D1       diff
1  2014-11-20 16:00:00 0.01000000
2  2014-11-20 17:00:00 0.02000000
3  2014-11-20 18:00:00 0.02500000
4  2014-11-20 19:00:00 0.03000000
25 2014-11-21 16:00:00 0.04000000
26 2014-11-21 17:00:00 0.06000000
27 2014-11-21 18:00:00 0.07333333
28 2014-11-21 19:00:00 0.08666667
29 2014-11-21 20:00:00 0.10000000
```

Comment: Thanks @iembry, I get the following errors and Warnings: > xi <- as.numeric(Lines[which(is.na(Lines$diff == TRUE)), 1])
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion.... and... > interps1 <- na.interp1(as.numeric(Lines$Time), Lines$diff, xi = xi, na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 3)
Error: could not find function "na.interp1"

Comment: > source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iembry-USGS/ie2misc/master/R/na.interp1.R")
Error in source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iembry-USGS/ie2misc/master/R/na.interp1.R") : 
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iembry-USGS/ie2misc/master/R/na.interp1.R:1:2: unexpected input
1: ï»

Comment: I used the following commands: devtools::install_github("iembry-USGS/ie2misc")

library(iembry)  and got:                                                                                    > devtools::install_github("iembry-USGS/ie2misc")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘digest’
> 
> library(iembry)
Error in library(iembry) : there is no package called ‘iembry’